# Any way to have the "Log in to Experience as User" button open a "New Incognito Window"?

Tags: community, lightning-community, digital-experience

When using the "Log in to Experience as User" button on Contact the desktop session appears to be left active as well as the experience session.

Is there a way to avoid that to test purely the experience session permissions?

Comment: Do you have the password for the account? You can always log in directly if you have that.

Comment: No @sfdcfox I don't; this is a production org.

Comment: @Keith : you can get the login url of your portal and add a custom button or action logic to open it in a separate incognito window.

Comment: Thanks @AjaySFDC; can't modify the app right now. And AFAIK there is no API to "log in as User" without having to input credentials? Or is there?

Comment: I'm not able to understand your requirement completely, but maybe you can try using external credentials option with JWT - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_create_edit_oath_ext_cred.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi @AjaySFDC, This relates to Digital Experiences; thanks for your comments.